# An error has occured: Installation is not enabled for chrome extension in puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I am trying to download a chrome extension in puppeteer, by actually clicking it, and I get an error saying 'installation is not enabled' when clicking add extension.

Any reason why?

Comment: Are you in headless or headful mode? Can you share your script? (Especially what launch args do you use)

Comment: I figured it out using a launch argument.

Comment: Great! Can you kindly post your solution as an answer below? This can be useful for others as well!

Comment: var options = {
            headless: false,
            args: [
              '--disable-extensions-except=C:/Users/Salvatore/Desktop/SneakerBot/Node Bot/buster crx',
              '--load-extension=C:/Users/Salvatore/Desktop/SneakerBot/Node Bot/buster crx',
            ]
          }

Comment: BTW this also works for unpacked extensions - it is possible to pass in a path of a directory to both args.

Comment: It is important that relative path doesn't work, only full path.